# How to create a subdomain for each user's profile page in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, subdomain, user-profile

I am working on a ruby on rails music webapp (alphabeatsmusic.com), in which I would like to link artists' profile page with the domain: artistname.alphabeatsmusic.com

Please can you advise steps to achieve this? My experience with coding is fairly low - thus attempts using other links did not succeed.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?autoplay=true